# how to pass react-router-dom props & normal props

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I know the way use react-router-dom props . that is like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

const  AAA : React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({history}) => {
.
.
.
}
```

and I know how to use props sended by parent component that is like this

```
import React from 'react';

const AAA = props => {
.
.
.
}
```

but I don't know how to use both of this.

please give me advice.

Comment: you don't know how to handle such a combined "type" in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

`{history}` prop that you are using is using object destructuring.

You can either do this:

1. You can directly use `history` and `sampleProp` in your code.

```js
<ChildComponent samepleProp />
```

```js
const ChildComponent = ({history, samepleProp}) = {}
```

2. Or you can do it like this.

You have to use `props.history` and `props.sampleProp`

```js
<ChildComponent samepleProp />
```

```js
const ChildComponent = (props) = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform destructuration on an Object. You will have access only to properties which you specify.

As all props pass to a component are accessible via the argument which It's constructor receive generally named as `props` you can access them via `props.prop_name`

If you have a `ChildComponent` within which you want to have access to `router` properties like **history, location, match** and properties which It receive from it parent you can perform that like this.

consider in the `ParentComponent` you render the `ChildComponent` like this

```
<ChildComponent name="The child component" />
```

To access both `router` parameter and props receive from the parent you do this

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const ChildComponent = (props) => {

    // Here you have access to react-router-dom parameter

    const {history, location, match} = props;

    return <div>
         
         {/* 
             to access name props receive from the parent
             component you perform it like below 
         */}

         {props.name} 

    </div>
}

export default withRouter(ChildComponent);
```